# What would have been the scenario of mathematics if we had geometric pictures of vector spaces with $>3$ dimensions?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, analytic-geometry

I was reading Apostol and in it's $12^{th}$ chapter (page 446) it said-

> Unfortunately, the geometric pictures which are a great help in motivating and illustrating 
>   vector concepts when $n = 1, 2,$ and $3$ are not available when $n > 3$; therefore, the study 
>   of vector algebra in higher-dimensional spaces must proceed entirely by analytic means.

So, I was wondering what would have been the state of mathematics if we had geometric pictures of vector spaces with $>3$ dimensions? Would we be able to solve more geometric problems?
I think we still would have the same amount of results but enriched by their geometric understanding. Right?

Comment: This isn't a mathematical question, and you'll only get opinion-based answers. At best it's a psychological matter.

Comment: Who knows? Unfortunately we only have one unique past (without taking in account the different interpretations applied on this past).

Comment: I would say "nothing much".  The quote simply says "pictures are of great help".  They don't really change anything important.

Answer (score 1):

Pictures are part of communication between mathematicians. For whatever reasons of biological evolution, the wetware of human mathematicians is not well-designed to visualize static pictures in dimensions above 3, hence such pictures are not of much use to us. Nonetheless, we have developed pretty great tools for working in higher dimensions, and amazing theorems have been proved in high dimensional topology.

In fact, intuition seems to vary highly amongst mathematicians. There even seems to be a high variation of such basic abilities as: visualizing static pictures of 3-dimensional objects; rapidly manipulating linear strings of symbols; and so on. Despite such variation, we nonetheless seem able to communicate with each other using the language of mathematics.

It seems to me that the situation is pretty much the same for the good high dimensional visualizers amongst us (e.g. Michael Freedman who solved the [4-dimensional Poincare Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture)). Whatever their internal visualizations that they cannot convey to us, they have nonetheless figured out how to communicate their ideas using the language of mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

We get so much insight from 1D/2D/3D graphical diagrams ([example](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery)) that there is no much doubt on my side that a 4D canvas would give additional insight if we were beings of 4 spatial dimensions with appropriate senses and intellect. This of course includes 4D vector algebra.